# Create loop for js functions with different indices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this part of code that works great for me. It is creating two circle progress bars and animating them depending on the given percentage values.

There are two functions `timer_0` and `timer_1` that are almost the same except the indices. How can I create a loop and invoke these functions by their suffixes. Any help will be appreciated.

Html part

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="progress progress-radial">

      <svg width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 160 160" data-progress-value="95">
        <circle class="progress-meter" cx="80" cy="80" r="78" fill="none" stroke-width="4" />
        <circle style="stroke-dasharray: 490.088; stroke-dashoffset: 50.000;" stroke='red' class="progress-value" cx="80" cy="80" r="78" fill="none" stroke-width="4" />
      </svg>

      <div class="progress-body">
        <div class="progress-data-value">
          60%
        </div>
        <div class="progress-title">
          Skill
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="progress progress-radial">

      <svg width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 160 160" data-progress-value="95">
        <circle class="progress-meter" cx="80" cy="80" r="78" fill="none" stroke-width="4" />
        <circle style="stroke-dasharray: 490.088; stroke-dashoffset: 50.000;" stroke='red' class="progress-value" cx="80" cy="80" r="78" fill="none" stroke-width="4" />
      </svg>

      <div class="progress-body">
        <div class="progress-data-value">
          20%
        </div>
        <div class="progress-title">
          Skill
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Javascript part

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('circle.progress-value').each(function(){
        progress_circle_set = 100 - parseInt( jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.progress-data-value').text() );
        jQuery(this).attr('data-progress-set', Math.round(progress_circle_set * 490 / 100));
    });

    timer_0();
    function timer_0() {
        progress_circle_set = jQuery('.progress-value').eq(0).attr('data-progress-set');

        if ( jQuery('.progress-value').eq(0).attr('data-progress-current' ) ) {
            progress_circle_current = jQuery('.progress-value').eq(0).attr('data-progress-current' );
        } else {
            progress_circle_current = 490;
        }

        progress_circle_current--;
        jQuery('.progress-value').eq(0).attr('data-progress-current', progress_circle_current );

        if ( progress_circle_current != progress_circle_set ) {
            jQuery('circle.progress-value').eq(0).css('stroke-dashoffset', progress_circle_current );
        } else {
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(timer_0, 10);
    }

    timer_1();
    function timer_1() {
        progress_circle_set = jQuery('.progress-value').eq(1).attr('data-progress-set');

        if ( jQuery('.progress-value').eq(1).attr('data-progress-current' ) ) {
            progress_circle_current = jQuery('.progress-value').eq(1).attr('data-progress-current' );
        } else {
            progress_circle_current = 490;
        }

        progress_circle_current--;
        jQuery('.progress-value').eq(1).attr('data-progress-current', progress_circle_current );

        if ( progress_circle_current != progress_circle_set ) {
            jQuery('circle.progress-value').eq(1).css('stroke-dashoffset', progress_circle_current );
        } else {
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(timer_1, 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like something that would benefit from being defined as a [widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating code is never a good practice. If you take a closer look, you may find that the only difference are these lines:

```
jQuery('.progress-value').eq(0)
jQuery('circle.progress-value').eq(0)
```

And therefore, you can do this instead:

```
function timer(i) {
    progress_circle_set = jQuery('.progress-value').eq(i).attr('data-progress-set');

    if ( jQuery('.progress-value').eq(i).attr('data-progress-current' ) ) {
        progress_circle_current = jQuery('.progress-value').eq(i).attr('data-progress-current' );
    } else {
        progress_circle_current = 490;
    }

    progress_circle_current--;
    jQuery('.progress-value').eq(i).attr('data-progress-current', progress_circle_current );

    if ( progress_circle_current != progress_circle_set ) {
        jQuery('circle.progress-value').eq(i).css('stroke-dashoffset', progress_circle_current );
    } else {
        return;
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        timer(i);
    }, 10);
}

timer(0);
timer(1);
```

And more generally:

```
var numOfTimers = 2;
for(var i = 0; i < numOfTimers; i++){
    timer(i);
}
```